# How to create a GROUP_CHAT space using Google Chat API?

Tags: google-chat

I'm trying to create a GROUP_CHAT space using the Google Chat API, but I didn't find how to do it.
I can create message to an existing GROUP_CHAT space, but I cannot create a new GROUP_CHAT space, because it seams that the GROUP_CHAT space type is not supported by the API.

Is there a way to create a new GROUP_CHAT space using the Google Chat API ?
MAybe by creating a message to it, but in this case, do you have any example ?

Thank you.
Regards.

I did try this code :

```
Space space = new Space();
space.setDisplayName("Display Name");
space.setExternalUserAllowed(true);
space.setSpaceType("GROUP_CHAT");
Space createdSpace = chatService.spaces().create(space).execute();
```

And I get an error message : Specify a space type of SPACE. Other space types aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

> space.setSpaceType("SPACE");

I recreated the same here https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22displayName%22%3A%22Display%20Name%22%2C%22externalUserAllowed%22%3Atrue%2C%22spaceType%22%3A%22SPACE%22%7D%7D

It's probably saying that when you're using the spaces api, only use "SPACE" as the space type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).